# Git Same File on multiple origins with different content

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

I have two Gitlab Self Hosted instances. Let's say `code.apple.com` and `code.google.com`. Both instances has a repo called `awesome-website`. I am using Gitlab CI/CD pipelines to deploy websites to two different domains i-e `awesome-website.google.com` and `awesome-website.apple.com`. Gitlab CI uses a file called `.gitlab-ci.yml` for deployment pipelines. I have added two remote origins which are in sync. I want to keep differnt `.gitlab-ci.yml` file on each repo so that I can deploy websites accoringly.

How can I achieve this?

I can not put the file in '.gitignore' because it will delete from the repo on next push.

I have tried `git update-index assume-unchanged` and `git update-index --skip-worktree` but no luck so for. File changed in one gitlab repo affects the other repo.

Thanks

Comment: Use a single `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, and use something else to distinguish the differences : env variables set at pipeline start for example

Comment: Use some env variables set on GitLab to manage the differences

Answer (score 1):

If the difference is minor you can set a variable

https://gitlab.com/help/ci/variables/README#variables

[image: CI/CD Settings]

If you want more flexibility you can create two files, one for each, then each gitlab instance will use a specific one

https://gitlab.com/help/ci/pipelines/settings#custom-ci-configuration-path

[image: Custom CI Configuration path]

Comment: Orel, Thanks for the answer. Its  a quick hack. But I feel there must be some way in git to handle this type of scenarios.